# How to make a French keyboard's dot key (numeric keypad) work as input with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard

I'm designing a C++/Qt application. I'm with a French keyboard on a French Windows environment.

When I try to type a decimal number in a QDoubleSpinBox control, pressing the dot numeric keypad button does nothing....I would expect it to insert a decimal separator!

Here is a very simple Qt program isolating the problem:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QDialog>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    Dialog()
    {
        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout( this );

        layout->addWidget( new QLabel( QLocale().toString( 3.14 ), this ) );
        layout->addWidget( new QDoubleSpinBox( this ) );
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I compiled it with Visual Studio 2010 and 5.2.1 on a French PC.

When the dialog opens:

[image]

Then:

- The QLabel displays "3,14" which means french QLocale is correctly used (else, it would display 3.14, english default stype). OK
- The QDoubleSpinBox diplays "0,00". OK
- I can type a decimal value in the spinbox using the ',' standard keyboard key. OK
- I cannot type a decimal value in the spinbox using the '.' standard keyboard key. OK
- **But when I press the dot key from my numerical French keypad, nothing happens!** This is supposed to enter a decimal separator, whatever locale setting is being used!

I'm looking for a gloabl solution (at QApplication level), not something at QSpinBox level because I have many of them in my original project.

Comment: Correct me, if I am wrong - you want to press '.' button, and expect it will print ',' instead, because your locale uses ',' as a decimal separator?

Comment: Exactly. Like Microsoft Excel does: if I press "1" "." and "2" from the keypad, is writes "1,2" in the selected cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41256 is fixed, the solution is an application-global event filter, so that any use of the '.' key on the numeric keyboard (and only there) is turned into a ',' -- on systems where the default locale uses ',' as decimal separator.

```
class GlobalEventFilter : public QObject
{
public:
    explicit GlobalEventFilter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev) override {
        if (ev->type() == QEvent::KeyPress || ev->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease) {
            QKeyEvent *kev = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(ev);
            if (kev->key() == Qt::Key_Period && (kev->modifiers() & Qt::KeypadModifier)) {
                QChar decimalPoint = QLocale().decimalPoint();
                if (decimalPoint == QLatin1Char(',')) {
                    QKeyEvent modifiedKeyEvent(kev->type(), Qt::Key_Comma, kev->modifiers(), QString(decimalPoint), kev->isAutoRepeat(), kev->count());
                    qApp->sendEvent(obj, &modifiedKeyEvent);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

And in your `main()`, add `qApp->installEventFilter(new GlobalEventFilter(qApp));`.

I tested this to work on a French Linux system.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to check that the receiver (obj) is a QDoubleSpinBox, so this event filter affects all widgets, even lineedits and textedits. If this isn't wanted, wrap the 3 lines starting at `QKeyEvent modifiedKeyEvent` into an if statement like this: `if (qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox *>(obj) || (obj->parent() && qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox *>(obj->parent())) {`.

Comment: True, I noticed that. But I would recommand to have the same behaviour for `QDoubleSpinBox` and `QLineEdit`, else it may be confusing to the user.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should be using [QDoubleSpinBox](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdoublespinbox.html#validate), instead of QSpinBox. As the documentation for [QSpinBox](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html) states:

> *use QDoubleSpinBox for floating point values.*

As you can see from [QDoubleSpinBox::textFromValue](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdoublespinbox.html#textFromValue)

> *This virtual function is used by the spin box whenever it needs to display the given value. The default implementation returns a string containing value printed using QWidget::locale().toString(value, QLatin1Char('f'), decimals()) and will remove the thousand separator.*

Comment: Don't understand your post...I am using a QDoubleSpinBox, check the code I posted....and it does not work!

Comment: Your code did not show QDoubleSpinBox, until you edited it, after my answer!

Comment: If it still doesn't work, I suggest looking into creating a class derived from QObject, overloading its keyPressEvent to intercept the '.' key and installing it as an event filter on the widgets that you want for this behaviour. You can then detect the '.' and replace it with QLocale::decimalPoint() - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter

Comment: No, I edited only the second sentence that was wrongly mentioning `QSpinBox`. The code + screenshot always used `QDoubleSpinBox`, I did not edit those. It may make sense to delete your post because it does not answer the original question...

Comment: Sure, event filters could help, but I don't consider this as an acceptable solution because it would have to be done for every  `QDoubleSpinBox` of my project and there are tones of them (It's a huge project that did not have problems with Qt 4.7, problem appears when I moved to 5.2)

Comment: If the same code worked on Qt 4, but you've found this issue with Qt 5, I suggest posting it as a bug to the Qt team.

Comment: As for having tonnes of QDoubleSpinBox, perhaps you can automate finding objects of that class and installing the event filter.

Comment: You're right, I filled a qt bug: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-41256

Comment: I'll wait for a real solution ;-)

Comment: Your answer suggests to use a QDoubleSpinBox but I am already using one. Proposing to fill a Qt bug is a good idea but definitely not a solution...